# Msgbox YesNo error

Tags: .net, vb.net, messagebox

I get this error message: expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment

For this code

```
MsgBox("Do you really wish to delete " & txtLayerDelete.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes
```

txtLayerDelete is on a UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried to assign the `MsgBox` and are not using the method's return value.

```
MsgBox("Do you really wish to delete " & txtLayerDelete.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
```

Would be displaying the message box to your user, this method returns a `MsgBoxResult` object which you should use, as shown below.

```
Dim delete =  MsgBox("Do you really wish to delete " & txtLayerDelete.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

If delete = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
  'Your logic
End If
```

Alternative you can just add an If statement and do:

```
If MsgBox("Do you really wish to delete?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

End If
```

As an additional note the [MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) function appears to be outdated, you should try and use [`MessageBox.Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim delete = MessageBox.Show("Should this item be deleted", "Form Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

If delete = DialogResult.Yes Then

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way.  Note that MsgBox and MessageBox return a result that is an enumerated value.  MsgBox was replaced with MessageBox

```
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you really wish to delete " & txtLayerDelete.Text & "?", , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the methods return value, my friend.

It should be:

```
`Dim dialogDel = MsgBox("Do you really wish to delete " & txtLayerDelete.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)`

If dialogDel = DialogResult.Yes Then
 'Yes code.
Else
 'No code
End If
```

Your welcome :)

Comment: This approach required me to import system forms.  Doing so causes errors throughout my plug-in code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since everyone has shown you how to complete your task with an `IF Statement`, I will show you how I would do it.
Personally I prefer to use the `CASE statement` as I think it looks a lot more cleaner.

```
Select Case MsgBox("Do you really want to delete " & txtLayerDelete.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            ''DELETES
        Case MsgBoxResult.No
            ''NOTHING
    End Select
```

If you have an issues with the code I have provided you with, let me know :)